# Is there an elegant way to check if index can be requested in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, built-in

I am looking for an elegant way to check if a given index is inside a numpy array (for example for BFS algorithms on a grid).

The following code does what I want:

```
import numpy as np

def isValid(np_shape: tuple, index: tuple):
    if min(index) < 0:
        return False
    for ind,sh in zip(index,np_shape):
        if ind >= sh:
            return False
    return True

arr = np.zeros((3,5))
print(isValid(arr.shape,(0,0))) # True
print(isValid(arr.shape,(2,4))) # True
print(isValid(arr.shape,(4,4))) # False
```

But I'd prefer something build-in or more elegant than writing my own function including python for-loops (yikes)

Comment: Perhaps: `def isValid(np_shape: tuple, index: tuple): return (0, 0) <= index <= np_shape`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I've tried that: (0,0) <= (4,-1) returns True for some reason..

Comment: But, this form of `isValid` returns False (same as the posted question).

Comment: Shape and index are both tuples, and short ones at that.  Don't worry about loops.  The no-loop 'rule' applies to numpy arrays, especially long ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
def isValid(np_shape: tuple, index: tuple):
    index = np.array(index)
    return (index >= 0).all() and (index < arr.shape).all()

arr = np.zeros((3,5))
print(isValid(arr.shape,(0,0))) # True
print(isValid(arr.shape,(2,4))) # True
print(isValid(arr.shape,(4,4))) # False
```

Answer (score 2):

I have benchmarked the answers quite a bit, and come to the conclusion that actually the explicit for loop as provided in my code performs best.

Dmitri's solution is wrong for several reasons (tuple1 < tuple2 just compares the first value; ideas like np.all(ni < sh for ind,sh in zip(index,np_shape)) fail as the input to all returns a generator, not a list etc).

@mozway's solution is correct, but all the casts make it a lot slower. Also it always needs to consider all numbers for casting, while an explicit loop can stop earlier, I suppose.

Here is my benchmark (Method 0 is @mozway's solution, Method 1 is my solution):

[image]